# Getting dynamic date in oracle SQL query executed from python environment using cx_Oracle package

Tags: python, sql, pandas, cx-oracle

I'm trying to write a query which fetches the current date and gets the relevant log data. Have written a nested query which works from PL/SQL but it isn't working from Python environment. Please advise.

Working query for PL/SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TBLIRISVISITLOGS TLOG
WHERE TLOG.IVL_VISITDATE = (SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM DUAL)
```

When I execute this query in Python environment, it fetches an empty table.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `WHERE TLOG.IVL_VISITDATE = CURRENT_DATE`?

Comment: Because this script will run on a daily basis, I need to get current date for that day only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like I've found the solution:

```
from pandas import Timestamp as tstamp
test_query = """
SELECT * FROM TBLIRISVISITLOGS T WHERE T.IVL_LATITUDE>0 AND T.IVL_VISITDATE = TO_DATE('{CURR_DATE}','YYYY-MM-DD')
""".format(CURR_DATE=str(tstamp.now().date()))
```

Comment: Same comment: Why don't you simply use `WHERE TLOG.IVL_VISITDATE = CURRENT_DATE`?

Comment: Because it is part of an automated script that will run periodically every day, it will get data for only that day.

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` is Standard SQL's a placeholder for today's date, it's the same as `tstamp.now().date()`.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know, I'll try this and let you know.